# Join the content of files to one file

Tags: python

I have two files and I want to join the content of them into one file side-by-side, i.e., line n of the output file should consist of line n of file 1 and line n of file 2. The files have the same number of lines.

What I have until now:

```
with open('test1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('test2.txt', 'r') as f2:

    with open('joinfile.txt', 'w') as fout:

        fout.write(f1+f2)
```

but it gives an error saying -

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'file' and 'file'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are concatenating two file objects which you don't want

Comment: Any reason shell's `cat test1.txt test2.txt > joinfile.txt` does not fit your needs?

Comment: @eumiro: some windows got no cats ;)

Comment: For Windows you can use `copy /b test1.txt+test2.txt joinfile.txt`.

Comment: In the comment to my answer, the OP said more precisely what he wants. So the tools you proposed won't help, even though they perfectly fit for the question as it was initially.

Comment: @ThorstenKranz: In that case he can use `paste test1.txt test2.txt`

Comment: Sure, you're right. I also always prefer to use well-tested command line utilities. But if he already is in Python, e.g., in a webservice, GUI or whatever, than it is easier to use a pure-python solution. This makes Exception handling much easier and gives more flexibility.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" or similar to the title. Instead, click the green checkmark to accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try `itertools.chain()` and work line per line (you use "r" to open your files, so I assume you do not red binary files:

```
from itertools import chain

with open('test1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('test2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    with open('joinfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for line in chain(f1, f2):
            fout.write(line)
```

It works as generator, so no memory problems are likely, even for huge files.

**Edit**

New reuqirements, new sample:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

separator = " "

with open('test1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('test2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    with open('joinfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for line1, line2 in izip_longest(f1, f2, fillvalue=""):
            line1 = line1.rstrip("\n")
            fout.write(line1 + separator + line2)
```

I added a `separator` string which is put between the lines.

`izip_longest` also works if one file has more lines than the other. The fill_value `""` is then used for the missing line. `izip_longest`also works as generator.

Important is also the line `line1 = line1.rstrip("\n")`, I guess it's obvious what it does.

Comment: It doesn't join the line of the first file with the first line of the second file.

Comment: Oh, so your files have same number of lines and you want line n of `fout`be like line n of `f1` + line n of `f2`?

Comment: Yes it has the same number of lines and I want to join every line of one file with the other file

Comment: thank you i checked and it gives ValueError: too many values to unpack at izip. Maybe have I to use linen?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to define the fillvalue as a kwarg, fixed this in my sample.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your question as solved so it doesn't appear in the "unanswered"-section anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
fout.write(f1.read())
fout.write(f2.read())
```

Comment: This gives the content of first file online.

Comment: Hmm, I tested it with Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 and in `joinfile.txt` I got content of both test files.

Answer (score 1):

You are actualy concatenating 2 file objects, however, you want to conctenate strings.

Read the file contents first with f.read. For example, this way:

```
with open('test1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('test2.txt', 'r') as f2:
  with open('joinfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(f1.read()+f2.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use shutil.copyfileobj. You can easily combine it with glob.glob to concatenate a bunch of files by patterns

```
>>> import shutil
>>> infiles = ["test1.txt", "test2.txt"]
>>> with open("test.out","wb") as fout:
    for fname in infiles:
        with open(fname, "rb") as fin:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fin, fout)
```

Combining with glob.glob

```
>>> import glob
>>> with open("test.out","wb") as fout:
    for fname in glob.glob("test*.txt"):
        with open(fname, "rb") as fin:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fin, fout)
```

But over and above that if you are in a system where you can use posix utilities, prefer its use

```
D:\temp>cat test1.txt test2.txt > test.out
```

In case you are using windows, you can issue the following from command prompt.

```
D:\temp>copy/Y test1.txt+test2.txt test.out
test1.txt
test2.txt
        1 file(s) copied.
```

**Note**
Based on your latest update

> Yes it has the same number of lines and I want to join every line of
>   one file with the other file

```
with open("test.out","wb") as fout:
    fout.writelines('\n'.join(''.join(map(str.strip, e))
                  for e in zip(*(open(fname) for fname in infiles))))
```

And on posix system, you can do

```
paste test1.txt test2.txt
```